# SQL Subqueries COUNT CASE

Tags: sql, t-sql, conditional-statements, nested-attributes

I'd like a SELECT query to return specific value if the count of a nested subquery is 0 ...

```
SELECT
  ( SELECT (CASE COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END)
    FROM List
    WHERE Status = 1
      AND Deleted = 1
  ) AS Status
```

This does not work what is wrong with this syntax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you want a case statement that looks like this:

```
CASE
 WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM list WHERE Status = 1 AND Deleted = 1) THEN 'FALSE'
 ELSE 'TRUE'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is missing the WHEN keyword in the CASE statement.

```
SELECT
  ( SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END)
    FROM List
    WHERE Status = 1
      AND Deleted = 1
  ) AS Status
```

You can go with that or you can simplify the query by removing the outer SELECT statement. And, the parentheses are optional too.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END
FROM List
WHERE Status = 1
  AND Deleted = 1
```